# Sass not compiling with angular-cli

Tags: angularjs, angular, sass, angular-cli

I'm trying to use Sass with [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#css-preprocessor-integration) but it's not working. I'm getting the following error:

`EXCEPTION: Failed to load http://localhost:4200/app/app.component.sass`.

I've added `node-sass` to my `package.json`, changed `styleUrls` to `['app.component.sass']` and also set `"styleExt": "sass"` in the `angular-cli.json` file.

Am I missing something to make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add Sass compilation in Angular CLI 6: angular.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50165010/how-do-i-add-sass-compilation-in-angular-cli-6-angular-json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, there's a minor mistake in the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#css-preprocessor-integration).

`styleUrls` shouldn't have `scss` or `sass` as extension but `css` instead. Replacing `['app.component.sass']` by `['app.component.css']` solved the problem.

Comment: I am using angular-cli and My scss flies are getting compiled except the app.component.scss in root directory

Comment: So now your files are compiled from scss/sass to css? I'm struggling with the same problem and as I see, my .scss files from generated components are not compiled and used.

Comment: Hi, as of today, you just need to import your `scss` files in your component. See the [official docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-css-preprocessors).

Answer (score 6):

Actually it's not right for the moment you can create your projects with precompilers.You should create your project with it.

```
ng new my_project --style=sass
```

or if you want to use scss syntax go with:

```
ng new my_project --style=scss
```