# How do I add Sass compilation in Angular CLI 6: angular.json?

Tags: angular, npm, sass, angular-cli

I just created a new Angular project using the new Angular CLI 6.0, but I need to add Sass compilation to my project. I'm aware you can set a flag when you create a project, but my project is already created and work has been done.

The new configuration file that gets generated with the new Angular CLI is now called `angular.json` rather than `angular-cli.json`. The scheme for the file is also different, with new properties.

In the old `angular-cli.json` there is a section where you can set the `stylExt` like so,

```
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss"
}
```

but I'm not sure where exactly to put this, as after the `"test"` and `"lint"` properties, gives a lint error of:

`Matches multiple schemas when only one must validate.`

and building produces:

`Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "['defaults']" should NOT have additional properties(styleExt).`

Looking at [CLI's docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace) I'm not seeing anything that would indicate where to put `"styleExt"`.

I've seen other answers advising: `ng set defaults.styleExt scss` which throws`get/set have been deprecated in favor of the config command.`.

I tried `ng config set defaults.styleExt scss` and `npm config set defaults.styleExt scss` with the former throwing an error and the latter apparently having no effect on the file, but without error.

Comment: I would create a new project using the the flag `--style=scss` and then just look at how the `angular.json` is set up in the generated project and then copy the `angular.json` in your application

Comment: @JuvenileSnow You know that's a pretty good idea, lol. Little things like this make me wonder if I'm even cut out to start an app to begin with.

Comment: --style=scss @SmokeyDawson TY that saved me!

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Doing exactly what [Smokey Dawson commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50165010/how-do-i-add-sass-compilation-in-angular-cli-6-angular-json/50205876#comment87348040_50165010),

```
"projects": {
  "angular-app": {
    "root": "",
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "projectType": "application",
    "prefix": "app",
    "schematics": {
      "@schematics/angular:component": {
        "styleext": "scss"
      }
    },
    "architect": {...}
  }
}
```

The above is the result.
So in your app, under the key `schematics`,
add a  key `@schematics/angular:component`
with the key `styleext` set to `scss`.

This should be applied to your `angular.json` file in the root directory of your project.

Comment: And change `src/styles.css` references to `src/styles.scss` in `angular.json`

Comment: Yes, this does the trick. @Dico, do you have a link to a documentation for that "schematics" "styletext" topic please?

Comment: @Herr_Hansen, it's "styleext" (style extension), not "styletext".

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v6.0.0-rc.8/packages/%40angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json#L108-L112

Comment: [angular-workspace](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace), [@schematics/angular:component](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v6.0.0-rc.8/packages/%40angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json#L74-L144), [styleext](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v6.0.0-rc.8/packages/%40angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json#L108-L112)

Comment: I have SSR also, will this effect automatically at the time of build or I have to configure webpack build configuration for sass compilation?

Comment: I had a flag in schematics already that I had to remove, otherwise components never generated any scss or css -it was:   "inlineStyle": true,         had to remove that

Comment: And restart your server when you are done. If you use `ng serve` then restart that.

Answer (score 58):

In Angular 6, It's more easier then that. The compilation is handled automatically!
How that ?
To use **scss** at components level you need to name the file with the extension **scss** (same go for **less, styl**). And in your **component.ts** you change the corresponding style to **scss** too.

Here a screenshoot from the doc:
[image]

And to use Scss at a globale scale (src/styles.css), then you need to change styles.css to styles.scss (same go for less, styl ...etc). And then you go on angular.json and change the old styles.css to the new styles.scss value. As shown in the image bellow:

[image]

Here the link for the doc for the first part for the ones that want to explore themselves:
https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#non-css-style-files

**Now what about setting up, ng-cli so when generating new component the extension will be by default scss ?**
Use the `ng config` command as follow:

```
 ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss
```

That will update angular.json with:

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
        "styleext": "scss"
    }
}
```

Which is the equivalent to the old angular-cli.json

```
    defaults: {
        "styleext": "scss"
    }
```

That's for a project that is already started but not set to default to scss. If you are creating a new project then use the option `--style` to specify that as follow:

```
ng new my-project --style=scss
```

And you will not have to use the precedent command which is a config command that allow us to update the specified field in the angular.json file (because it will be already set).

Comment: But what do you do to see the generated css file? Do we need separate tooling?

Comment: look at this article too https://blog.angularindepth.com/this-is-how-angular-cli-webpack-delivers-your-css-styles-to-the-client-d4adf15c4975

Answer (score 3):

Currently on version 9.0.6 this is a little different. Per [Dico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6114803/dico) and [Smokey Dawson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8724160/smokey-dawson) above you would use the following in your angular.json:

```
"projects": {
    "angular-app": {
        "root": "",
        "sourceRoot": "src",
        "projectType": "application",
        "prefix": "app",
        "schematics": {
            "@schematics/angular:component": {
                "styleext": "scss"
            }
        },
        "architect": {...}
    }
}
```

But in later versions the **styleext** property has changed to just **style**. Sourced from Angular Github [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/9e950e42bd6d33a2a201f37ba4c37e50b15294f2/packages/schematics/angular/component/schema.json#L72).

Comment: `But in later versions the styleext property has changed to just style` => thanks for that, that was what I actually was looking for