# SCSS to CSS style sheet

Tags: css, angular, visual-studio-code, sass

I'm still new with web development. Right now, just new with angular. How can I change from SCSS to CSS stylesheet cause I accidently select SCSS style when I create a new angular project.

One more thing, how can I change terminal bar in VS Code from [image: image 1] to [image: image 2]. I tried to Google but can't find the answer.

Comment: look at root of project file "angular.json". settings store where.

Comment: You can write "normal CSS" inside SCSS files, so technically you don't need to change anything. Just write your CSS inside the SCSS files and all is good. If you ever want to try out SCSS then you can do so without any changes.

Answer (score 2):

### Configuring Your Default Angular Component Extension

To have Angular default to generating components with CSS files and not SCSS files, simply edit your configuration. Keep in mind you can still use CSS syntax inside SCSS files.

```sh
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext css
```

[You can also do this process by hand by editing your `angular.json` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50205876/2758250)

### VS Code Terminal Tabs

Open your VS Code settings and search for `terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled` and check the option named `Terminal > Integrated > Tabs`.